# Cordova Telerik Native transition plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, telerik

I would like to use this [plugin from Telerik] (http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/native-page-transitions) in my Cordova project.
I've followed the guide and use the following code to transition to another view:

```
window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
"href" : "#page-id"
});
```

But the view doesn't update. My index.html is structured so that each page is a section with a unique id. In their documentation they say the following

> So before the transition, but after the screenshot is created, the view needs to change. There are several ways to do this, but it's probably easiest to to let the plugin handle this for you. Every function accepts a 'href' parameter which you can fill with stuff like '#home', 'home.html', 'details.html?item=3', etc. Basically anything you'd normally put in a href tag to enable navigation in your app. Note that because of this approach even a classic frameworkless multi-page app can now have page transitions!

But who is hiding and showing the section? Is the plugin or do I need to do it?
I'm not using any framework like jquery mobile etc.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the mystery solved.

Your HTML structure needs to follow JQuery Mobile convention. So in order for views to change successfully you need to use divs with data-role="page", data-role="header" and so on.

This is not ideal if you have an HTML structure in place or would like to use HTML5.